# Collapsing toolbar layout is going to collapsed state automatically on start of activity

Tags: java, android, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout

I have a collapsing toolbar within an appbar layout. It contains a view pager as it's collapsing content and a pinned action toolbar. The activity also has a nested scroll view below the collapsing toolbar. The nested scroll view contains a google map fragment.

On start of the activity, the collapsing toolbar collapses automatically in some of the cases without programmatically collapsing it.

I have tried a combination of different scroll flags for my view with scroll|exitUntilCollapsed|enterAlways. 
I have also tried not showing the google map fragment but I can still reproduce it.

How can I stop it from collapsing automatically? Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

I know its late but still..

The reason collapsing toolbar automatically collapses on actvity start is because there may a view in <*include layout="@layout/content_scrolling" />* like edittext which gain its focus when activity is started..

To overcome this issue you can add the tag

> android:focusableInTouchMode="true"

to  or

```
<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
```

Hope it helps..:)

Happy Coding..:)